# Laravel Routes Wildcard

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5, wildcard

I'm new to Laravel and wondering if anyone can assist with wildcards in routes.php file

This is what I currently have

```
Route::post('/post/method1','postController@method1');
Route::post('/post/method2','postController@method2');
Route::post('/post/method3','postController@method3');
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve.

```
Route::post('/post/{variable}','postController@{variable}');
```

Help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Create a method in the controller to route the request based on the parameter value:

```
public function route(string $path){

   // define the allowed methods
   $allowedMethods = ['someMethodName', 'anotherMethodName'];

   // check if the path name is a method and is allowed
   if(in_array($path, $allowedMethods, true) && method_exists($this, $path)){

       // call method
       return $this->{$path}();
   }

   // handle error
}
```

Then just use the controller like you would do normally:

```
Route::post('/post/{variable}','postController@route');
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas

That would work but still not exactly what I'm looking for. I have lots of post requests and it would be easier if I could just create a function for each post request in the postController

    protected function variable1()
    {
        // code
    }

    protected function variable2()
    {
        // code
    }